# What is the efficiency of javascript .toUpperCase method?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, big-o

So this seems like a super basic question, but I'm wondering about javascript's built in .toUpperCase() method- is the time efficiency O(n) or O(1)?

I always just assumed it would be constant time, but now that I think about it ... "under the hood" wouldn't this method need to go through each character to check if it is lower case one by one? (therefore making it O(n)

Comment: Yes, internally strings have to be processed one character at a time (one codepoint, really).

Comment: O(n), you have to go through the chars and manipulate them. Also note that toUpperCase() does is Immutable, so it returns a copy of the string... So again O(n)

Comment: Even if it's not changing anything, it has to make a copy of the string, which is `O(n)`.

Comment: @barmar But wouldn't it be the fact that it has to iterate through each character that makes it O(n)? Isn't the "copying" portion just O(1)?

Comment: I’ve done some performance tests. The duration of `toUpperCase` seems to grow linearly with string length, though it’s extremely negligible.

Comment: @AljoshaNovakovic How would you copy a string in `O(1)`?

Comment: @Xufox Since JS strings are immutable, I guess it could just copy the pointer.

Comment: @Xufox `let myVar = "example"` Now when I run `myVar.toUpperCase()` it is going to return `"EXAMPLE"` but it won't alter myVar. In general, if I declare a variable `myNewVar = 1` then that is in constant time. So likewise, declaring `myUpperCase = myVar.toUpperCase()` should be constant time (if it wasn't for the fact that .toUpperCase is linear which we just established) .Unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm described in [`String.prototype.toLowerCase ( )`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.tolowercase) of the specification is O(n). Each codepoint of the original String (or String representation of the original object) is copied and converted to a new codepoint.

The fact that `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase` return new Strings (because JavaScript Strings are immutable) is enough to verify that the operation takes linear time, not constant.